# nvm not download specific version

Tags: python, node.js, macos, nvm

i am trying to install version 12 of node via nvm, but even though python is installed, python not found error is given at checksum time.

this nvm and python version :

```
~ % nvm --version
0.33.0

~ % python --version
Python 3.10.5
```

this is nvm error :

```
~ % nvm install 12
Downloading and installing node v12.22.12...
Local cache found: $NVM_DIR/.cache/bin/node-v12.22.12-darwin-arm64/node-v12.22.12-darwin-arm64.tar.xz
Computing checksum with shasum -a 256
Provided checksum to compare to is empty.
Checksum check failed!
Removing the broken local cache...
Downloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v12.22.12/node-v12.22.12-darwin-arm64.tar.xz...

Computing checksum with shasum -a 256
Provided checksum to compare to is empty.
tar: Error opening archive: Unrecognized archive format
Binary download failed, trying source.
Local cache found: $NVM_DIR/.cache/src/node-v12.22.12/node-v12.22.12.tar.xz
Checksums match! Using existing downloaded archive $NVM_DIR/.cache/src/node-v12.22.12/node-v12.22.12.tar.xz
./configure: line 3: exec: python: not found
nvm: install v12.22.12 failed!
```

this is nvm debug :

```
~ % nvm debug
nvm --version: v0.33.0
$SHELL: /bin/zsh
$HOME: /Users/onur.ozkir
$NVM_DIR: '$HOME/.nvm'
$PREFIX: ''
$NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX: ''
nvm current: none
which node: node not found
which iojs: iojs not found
which npm: /opt/homebrew/bin/npm
npm config get prefix: env: node: No such file or directory
npm root -g: env: node: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 3):

This could be an nvm version issue if you are using an older version on nvm on the new M1 macs

install the latest version of nvm like this

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.0/install.sh | bash
```

or using wget

```
wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.0/install.sh | bash
```

Remove the current references from your .zshrc or bash profile
You can also rm -rf ~/.nvm